# Google Places API - search global, not in specific region?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm building a service to search for tourist attractions based on a keyword around the world. For example, user searches for 'beach', id like top 20 beach destinations to be returned.

I'm using places api (textsearch) to query, and searching 'beach' works when I specify region = .au (for example).

My question is how can I go one step back, and search 'beach' across the globe, not within a specific region?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=beach&type=point_of_interest&region=au
```

Tried region=au,en - but places API only allows one region.
When excluding region parameter is searches geolocation based on your current location